# What to do if I want to Bentch, but I also want to keep drinking?

Tags: blessing, bentching, meal-seudah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuing to drink a Beverage after Birchas HaMazon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/continuing-to-drink-a-beverage-after-birchas-hamazon)

What should I do if I want to Bentch - for any number of reasons - but I want to continue drinking?

Should I:

- wait to Bentch until I've finished drinking;
- Bentch and make a new Berachah before and after drinking; or
- Bentch and make a Berachah after drinking?

What are the principles to consider?

Sources, please.

Comment: (Similar, but fundamentally different and not a dupe, IMHO): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18750/5

Comment: But itsn't it a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18662/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed. Oops.

Comment: Like I said over there: [bentching on a kos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/why-dont-people-bentch-on-a-kos-nowadays#comment18289_11969) would solve all these problems in a most efficient fashion...